# Htaccess file not working (like it doesnt exist)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Alright, so this is pretty frustrating for me. I have a simple php website and want I wanted is to remove the page extension (index.php to index). from what I read from guides, everyone pointed out that all I need to do is create a .htaccess file and paste this code in it.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

After doing so, I saw no change. 
after some testing, I noticed that even if the file contains errors (by just writing "TEST" in the file) nothing happens. So I guess I'm clearly missing something and could really use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have fullfilled these necessary conditions.

1. Need to have your webpages on apache server
2. Need to have .htaccess file in appropriate directory, where you want influence
3. In appropriate apache conf file you need to have this directive **`AllowOverride All`**. When you don't have this or have **`AllowOverride None`**, apache disregards .htaccess in your directory.

I think, you don't have properly configured third point.

Comment: yea. you were right! for some reason there was AllowOverride all (and not "All")

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: still not working, i think the problem is more to do with the file is not being used (i think), more than the actual content of the file

Comment: Do you have the .htaccess file in the root directory of /public_html/ ?  (the same directory as your landing page "index.php")